# If $\operatorname{Ric} (\partial _r, \partial_r) \ge \epsilon r^{-2}$ for $\epsilon > 1/4$, then the manifold is compact

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, compactness

I have to prove the following

> Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold with Ricci curvature bounded from below by $Ric(\partial_r,\partial_r)\ge \varepsilon r^{-2}$ for $r>1$ and some constant $\epsilon>1/4$. Prove that $M$ is compact.

It is similar to Myers' theorem. Any hint would be fantastic.

Comment: Did you try arguing as in Myer's theorem?

Comment: The only difference is about Ricci boundness. Namely, in the theorem is says $Ric(v,v)\ge (n-1)/r^2$ for $r>0$ and $n=\dim M$. My problem (it might be silly) is to ensure $\epsilon r^{-2}$ holds it. The latter does not depend of the dimension.